# Teach me how to design a nested computed property in ember.js

Tags: ember.js

I have a handful of computed properties defined on a component. I'd like to refactor these computed properties to live within a `messages` object on the component. When I make a call to get one of the computed properties elsewhere, I'm returned an instance of Ember's `ComputedProperty` object, rather then the translation string I expected. [Looking at the documentation, Ember.get should invoke the computed property and return the object itself, the property value or null](http://git.io/R3Bnvg).

What am I missing? How would I go about structuring these nested computed properties so that I can access them using the get/set interface elsewhere in the component?

---

```
App.ValidatedDateComponent = Ember.Component.extend({
  format: null,
  label: null,
  messages: {
    invalidDateMsg: (function() {
      return I18n.t('%{date} must be a valid date. %{format}', {
        date: this.get('label'),
        format: this.get('format')
      });
    }).property('label', 'format')
  },
  validate: function(value, status) {
    if (!moment(value).isValid()) {
      return status(false, Ember.get(this.messages, 'invalidDateMsg'));
    } else {
      return this._super(value, status);
    }
  }
});
```

Answer (score 0):

Ember only supports defining computed properties while extending `Ember.Object` class, the exception to the rule is while defining a `Ember.Mixin`.

#### Defining the top level of the nest

```
  var nest = Ember.Object.extend({
    foo: function() {
      return "something";
    }.property()
  });
```

#### Creating an instance of it

```
  App.IndexController = Em.ArrayController.extend({
    messages: nest.create()
  });
```

#### Template

```
  {{messages.foo}}
```

http://emberjs.jsbin.com/UhUvOvU/1/edit

So in your case you could, if you really wanted to, do:

```
  messages: Em.Object.extend({
    invalidDateMsg: function() {
      return I18n.t('%{date} must be a valid date. %{format}', {
        date: this.get('label'),
        format: this.get('format')
      });
    }.property('label', 'format')
  }).create(),
```